# Hook into 'save custom taxonomy' like 'save_post' in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, wordpress-hook

Is it possible to hook a function when a custom taxonomy term (which is not known beforehand), (preferably custom taxonomy child term) is edited/saved, just like the way we can hook into save_post when a post or page is saved?

What I want to do when the taxonomy term is saved:

```
function generate_pdf($slug) {
    wp_remote_get( etc... );
}
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that edit_${taxonomy} is the thing that I need, but I can't seem to push the $term_slug into the function:

```
function pdf_save_magazine($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {
    $term = get_term($term_id, $tt_id);
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
    wp_remote_get(
        'http://url-that-saves-pdf.com/?print='.$term_slug,
         array(
             'blocking' => false,
             'timeout' => 1,
             'httpversion' => '1.1'
          )
    );
}
add_action( 'edit_auteur', 'pdf_save_magazine', $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: The hook you are loking was maybe "edited_auter". Please note the past tense "ed". 

You can check here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question:

This works:

```
function pdf_save_magazine($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {
   $term = get_term($term_id, $taxonomy);
   $term_slug = $term->slug;
    wp_remote_get(
      'http://url-that-saves-pdf.com/?print='.$term_slug,
      array(
         'blocking' => false,
         'timeout' => 1,
         'httpversion' => '1.1'
      )
   );
}
add_action( 'edit_term', 'pdf_save_magazine', 10, 3 );
```